# 18.04 freezes with a old laptop

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, laptop, freeze, radeon

I have a rather old laptop, but I am particularly attached to it and would like to continue using it, if at all possible.

A couple of months ago, I updated the Lubuntu version from 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS and, unfortunately, I immediately ran into the problem of random freezes, especially if using Thunderbird and Chromium.

These are complete freezes, where the display is completely frozen, blinking lights for HDD access stop, and I cannot switch to terminal with <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, nor use **REISUB** or any other trick that I have read in this community.

One first thing I did was to run *Memtest+* for half a day, but the test did not highlight any memory failure.

Looking at the log files, both with `journalctl -b` or in `Xorg.0.log`, did not give me any hint of where the problem might be because they don’t record any useful information on the freeze.

Trying to make it more robust, I tried the following things:

[image: table of tests]

All the actions are not cumulative, meaning that I tested them starting from boot and editing the boot line in GRUB, then proceeding to login and open the same application(s).

Do you have any idea of how I troubleshoot and fix the cause for these crashes?

As a test, I run Lubuntu 18.04 from a usb and it also froze after some time I was navigating in Internet with Chrome and Firefox.

Doing the same experiment with Lubuntu 14.04, which I had available in  USB stick, it wasn't freezing at all.

---

Unfortunatly, after several attempts to find why my laptop freezes i could not find any solutions.

In the past few weeks I tried:

- Checking the CPU temperature with `acpitool -e`  but the temperature from the CPU is not reported
- Tried to detect thermal sensors with `sensor-detect` but none are found
- Checked if there is any driver managing the CPU power and found in `acpi-cpufreq` passive managemnt of the power, no active management of fans

The point I find strange is that the laptop works quite well if I connect with `ssh` and use it remotelly, but when I use the desktop environment, especially any browser, after a while it stops completely with HDD LED OFF, fan sometimes ON, no response whatsoever.

Comment: So RAM is OK. What is its amount?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 was *tested* to upgrade to 14.10 (the next release) and to 16.04 LTS (the next LTS).  If you skipped from 14.04 to 18.04 then you are outside of anything tested so I'd suggest re-install.  How much RAM do you have? and what size swap file (or swap partition) are you using?  What type of laptop are you using?  (cpu is?)

Comment: How much RAM, what processor? Which ISO did you use? I recently had to use the **alternate** ISO for Lubuntu (Bionic Beaver), when installing on a i686 notebook, Toshiba Tecra A5, with just 512 MB RAM, and it works perfectly. However, the standard ISO wouldn't install and kept on hanging. Using the alternate ISO instead, fixed the hanging issue.

Comment: The RAM is about 770MB and the SWAP area in the disk is about 4GB. I tested it by using a program like Gimp and opening many images to exceed the the memory in the Ram and it seemed to work properly.

Comment: The actual version of the Lubuntu I'm using is uname -r  > 5.4.0-66-generic. I remember installing the version 16.04 before installing the 18.04, but I' m not so sure .

Comment: I will add some log files to help describe the system I'm using, I hope they are of help.

Comment: Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               13
Model name:          Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.00GHz
Stepping:            8
CPU MHz:             600.000
CPU max MHz:         1500.0000
CPU min MHz:         600.0000
lags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx bts cpuid est tm2 pti

Comment: Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 25 bytes
System Information
 Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard 
 Product Name:                                 
 Version: F.55
 Serial Number:                                 
 UUID: Not Settable
 Wake-up Type: Power Switch

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
 Manufacturer: COMPAL
 Product Name: 0860
 Version: 8051 Version 24.56
 Serial Number:

Comment: Handle 0x000D, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00000000000
 Ending Address: 0x0000FFFFFFF
 Range Size: 256 MB
 Physical Device Handle: 0x000A
 Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
 Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
 Starting Address: 0x00010000000
 Ending Address: 0x0002FFFFFFF
 Range Size: 512 MB
 Physical Device Handle: 0x000B
 Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000C
 Partition Row Position: 2

Comment: `uname` provides details of the linux kernel, not of Lubuntu. The 5.4 kernel was the last HWE for 18.04/bionic being the GA kernel of 20.04/focal (none of which relate to Lubuntu itself; but the stack underneath). Pentium M is old & has flaws (intel say so) and I've got 2x (pentium M) ibm thinkpads that operate much better using the GA kernel (4.15) and two newer pentium thinkpads that don't mind the HWE kernel. I suspect you're using an old chrome (chrome no longer support the processor as I understand it; freezing during browsing was the issue & google dropped support)

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV250/M9 GL [Mobility FireGL 9000/Radeon 9000] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Compaq Computer Corporation RV250/M9 GL [Mobility FireGL 9000/Radeon 9000]
 Flags: bus master, stepping, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 128, IRQ 10
 Memory at 98000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
 I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
 Memory at 90400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: radeon
 Kernel modules: radeonfb, radeon

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04 reached EOL in 2017-April, and isn't a good comparison for anything related to browsers (`firefox` etc ran different code back then that ran much better on older CPUs, but due to security issues that code was replaced with safer code..). Refer firefox documentation for details there (or whatever browser you use...)   You need RAM... I tested on `hp d220mt (dr159p), (celeron 2ghz, 1gb (732mb useable), 82845G/GL Brookdale-G/GE (i915))` which had 732MB of useable RAM and it was a pain, devices with 1GB were 120% easier to use, thus I ignored devices <1GB available RAM.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and installed 2GB of RAM on my HP `zt3000 (Pentium M 2GHz, [AMD/ATI] RV250/M9 GL with radeon driver)` and used it with Lubuntu 18.04. The result is tht it **still freezes at random times**, both using firefox or chrome.

Comment: I also tried the `mitigations=off` in the GRUB line to exclude security patches in case they would have any influence, but didn´t have any effect on the problem.

Comment: I would likely validate your hardware, have you done a *cap-scan* & motherboard check? PSU check? etc. I'd test it on very different software stack (ie. a *live* system with very different stack to Lubuntu 18.04 you've got problems with) to see if it still occurs there.. If it occurs on very different software (other GNU/Linux, a BSD etc) then it's likely hardware related which you can confirm with other OSes. Also check temperature (pentium Ms stop if too hot so they don't cook themselves & cause warranty claim, ie. freezing is intentional; so check the fans & laptop cooling..)

Comment: CI checked the HW and apparently all is fine but... you must be right that something should be wrong with the temperature control of the processor. In fact by running `lm-sensors`, `acpi -t` or `sensors-detect`, it appears that there is no service monitoring the temperature of the device.

Comment: `gcbcn@laptop:~$ ll /sys/class/thermal/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Mar 13 14:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root 0 Mar 13 14:01 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Mar 13 14:02 cooling_device0 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device0/`

Comment: `acpi -V` show there is a cooling device, but it is always stating **Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 10**. Any idea whay it is not changing?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to get to a stage where the system is no longer freezing.

First of all, I noticed that the system was freezing mainly when there were applications using the network, like Thunderbird, Chromium Firefox and the like, when clicking to access some content, but would not freezing if using applications not using it.

This prompted me to:

- Check if the NetworkManager was posting any error in the logs by reviewing the journal with `sudo journalctl -b`. However, I could not see any error related to the network card or network configuration.
- I also checked if the traffic of the network sockets was normal with `ss -tan` and `ethtool eth0` and `tcpdump -ni eth0` but I couldn't find anything strange with the output of these commands.
- Therefore, I resolved to install strace with `sudo apt-get install strace`
- Create a directory to store the strace output `mkdir ./Downloads/strace`
- Run Chromium, Firefox or thunderbird under that tracer, for example `strace -C -f -c ./firefox &>straceoutput.txt`
- Examined the output of the various programs with `vi straceoutput.txt` especially at the bottom of the file `SHFT+g` to see what the program was doing last, just before hanging
- Noticed that the point where the programs were hanging showed access to networks services

`[pid  1757] recvmsg(4, {msg_namelen=0}, 0) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.000028> [pid  1757] poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=33, events=POLLIN}], 3, 0) = 0 (Timeout) <0.000028>`

With this hint, I could only suspect that the access to the network was not working properly, therefore I disconnected the lan cable and connected to the WiFi so as to switch network access.

Changing the network access for the WiFi made the trick and allows me to work without hangs.

I can consider the issue of old PC hanging with the 18.04 SOLVED and will open a new question to understand why the NIC connection is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a further update to solve the hanging with the network cable connected.

I installed a low latancy kernel with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04
```

and the problem with hangs of the old laptop with the lan cable is completely gone.